# Java: How does automatic casting work?

Tags: oop, inheritance

From a book:

> What if you want to call a method that’s defined by a subclass from an object
>   that’s referenced by a variable of the superclass? Suppose that the SoftBall class
>   has a method named riseBall that isn’t defined by the Ball class. How can you
>   call it from a Ball variable? One way to do that is to create a variable of the sub-class and then use an assignment statement to cast the object:"

```
Ball b = new SoftBall();
SoftBall s = (SoftBall)b;
// cast the Ball to a SoftBall
s.riseBall();
```

I don't understand this. Why can't I just directly call the method from the variable **b**? (The variable **b** in this case holds a *Softball* object). Why the casting?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> How can you call it from a Ball variable?

You can't. The compiler doesn't know that this `Ball` is a `SoftBall` as opposed to a `BaseBall`.

You have to cast explicitly. This is merely a way of saying to the compiler: "I know more about the type of this instance than you". The compiler trusts you (mostly: it wouldn't let you cast it to, say, a `String`), and lets you deal with the consequences (e.g. a potential `ClassCastException`)