# Java can not find methods like addFirst or addLast

Tags: java

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.LinkedList;
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
        list.addLast("string");
        list.removeLast();
    }
}
```

When I compile the code:

```
$ javac Test.java
Test.java:6: error: cannot find symbol
        list.addLast("string");
            ^
  symbol:   method addLast(String)
  location: variable list of type List<String>
Test.java:7: error: cannot find symbol
        list.removeLast();
            ^
  symbol:   method removeLast()
  location: variable list of type List<String>
2 errors
```

If I instantiate a LinkedList with LinkedList on both sides, then there will be no errors. I have learned that putting List on the left side is better. Why did this happen?

Update #1
If the variable `list` is of type `List`, why does the following code print `true`:

```
class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
       List<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();
       System.out.println(list instanceof LinkedList);
    }
}
```

What I interpret from the result of the above code is that `list` is an instance of `LinkedList`. If it's an instance of `LinkedList`, why can't it call methods declared and defined in `LinkedList`?

Update #2
There is `forEach` method in `ArrayList` but not in `List`. Why am I still be able to call `forEach` method on the `list` variable after I do

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Does this have something to do with lambda expression?

Comment: The compiler's not the only one, the [JavaDoc for `List`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) fail to find them either.  since `list` is just an instance of `List`, the functionality you're attempting to use isn't exposed to it.  `addFirst` and `removeLast` are only defined as part of `LinkedList` (see the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)), so only variables who are of the type `LinkedList` can access them, try `LinkedList <String> list = new LinkedList<String>();` instead

Comment: addLast method is in LinkList class but not in List Interface use like this LinkedList<String> list = new LinkedList<String>();

Comment: See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50268992/java-calling-a-subclass-method-from-superclass-variable/50269092#50269092

Answer (score 7):

> Why did this happen?

Java is a statically typed language. This means that the compiler looks at the declared type of the variable (not the object that may be inside it) to decide if the method exists or not.

The declared type `List` does not have these methods. They have been added in `LinkedList` (and come from the [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) interface for "linear collections that support element insertion and removal at both ends")

> I have learned that putting List on the left side is better.

Yes, this is called "coding to the interface". It avoids that you write code that only works with a specific implementation of that interface, and makes it possible to change the implementation without updating calling code.

But it only works if the interface provides everything you need.

In your case, you want to use `addLast`, which is not part of the general `List` interface. So you have to use the interface provided by [`Deque`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Deque.html) (or just `LinkedList` directly).

> There is `forEach` method in `ArrayList` but not in `List`.

`forEach` is defined by [`Iterable`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Iterable.html) which is the super-interface of all these things. As such, it is available in `List` as well.

> If it's an instance of `LinkedList`, why can't it call methods declared and defined in `LinkedList`?

Again: static typing. The actual runtime instance inside the variable may very well be of a more specific type than the variable is declared to be. But the *compiler* at *compile-time* can only do *static* analysis, i.e. look at the source code and the declared types of methods, fields and variables, not at anything that happens during program execution.

Comment: Thank you very much! What confuses me now is that `list` turns out to be also of type `LinkedList`. Please see Update #1 in my edited question.

Answer (score 1):

The Java List interface does not define an addLast or removeLast method. Since you declared your variable as a List rather than a LinkedList, you'll only be able to access the members defined on the List interface. See [List documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html) and [LinkedList documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/LinkedList.html)

Answer (score 0):

Well , it just because there is no "addLast()" method stated in java.util.List , the compiler only konws that the variable list is a instance of java.util.List and it will try to find a method named addLast() in List but get nothing , so it alarmed. 
And it seems that you may need to learn more about the Java's **Inheritance and polymorphism** system.

Answer (score 0):

The declared type you have given is List and the assigned type is `LinkedList`. Though the object is of `LinkedList`, it will only support the method which are present in declaring type and in your case it's List,which doesn't come with the methods which are specific to `LinkedList` Only. List is an `Interface` and is implemented by `ArrayList<>` as well. Now if we will keep these methods in the interface then every implementing class implement these methods as well and hence there will be no point of Single Responsibility and concern separation.